# defining, adding/subtracting (with one another), printing and defining variables in if then statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know im asking about a lot here but any help on variables will be appreciated examples like how to add and subtract 2 different variables together printing them along with regular "text" and any other variable knowledge will be helpful

Comment: You can google that, or check any basic tutorial

Comment: Welcome to SO. There are tons of ressouces out there in the web that can help you with that. Also that would be a lot faster to find than by setting up an SO question. So much for the downvotes.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how stackoverflow works and how to ask good  questions. Then come back and [edit] your question. Include the code of what you've tried as a [mcve], plus any error messages. Ask specific questions. Most people are happy to help, but don't want to do your work for you. Questions like "how do I do x?" that don't show any research effort on your end are likely to get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
inbetweenVar = var1 - var2
print(string(inbetweenVar) + " sample text")
```